# Refresh previous page API when Navigator.pop() is called

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have the following code in flutter where I'm first getting the data into the page:

```
Future<void> _getGoalsList() async {
    final response =
        await http.post(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:1111/goal/getGoals/1'));
    final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    final goalsList = responseData['getGoals'];
    goalsList.forEach((goal) {
      goals.add(Goals(
          id: goal['id'],
          goal_name: goal['goal_name'],
          goal_picture: goal['goal_picture']));
    });
    setState(() {
      _goalList = goals;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getGoalsList();
  }
```

And in this same page I have a button for going to a page to add new goals:

```
FloatingActionButton.small(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/addGoals');
  },
),
```

Now in my add goals page I have a confirm button that takes me back to the previous page:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    _addGoalToList();
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
  child: Text('Confirm'),
),
```

Now I want the _getGoalsList API to be called whenever the user clicks confirm so it can fetch the new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a boolean to check whether data has been added to list or not.
Based on the data you can pass assign the value to `isUpdated` variable.

```js
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    bool isUpdated = false;
    _addGoalToList();
    isUpdated = true;
    Navigator.pop(context,isUpdated);
  },
  child: Text('Confirm'),
),
```

In your list page, simply check for the result of page.

```
FloatingActionButton.small(
  onPressed: () async{
    final result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/addGoals');
    if(result = true){
    
    // code to update the list
    _getGoalsList();
 
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: This just stacks it again with the old ones and the new entry isnt even shown

Comment: Also, Don't forget to clear your list before API Call as list holds your old data.

Comment: Ah yes that was it!